# How to set compiler in phoronix-test-suite

Tags: performance-testing

I am using phoronix test suite to run benchmark of clang and gcc compilers.
I export the CC=clang and CXX=clang++ environment variables before I run the test.
But looking at top, I see that the compiler used is gcc.

So my question is - how do I configure phoronix to run the tests with clang compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sure you re-install the test, e.g. CC=clang CXX=clang++ phoronix-test-suite force-install . On some versions of PTS though it will detect you changed those environment variables, then prompt you to re-install. But if you always just use "phoronix-test-suite run" it won't re-install/re-compile the tests.